# Right ALT sends two virtual key codes

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

In my hook procedure (for keyboard) when I click right alt it sends me two codes on press and two on release:

The code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK Recorder::keyboardHookProcedure( int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) {
    if( code < 0 )
        return CallNextHookEx( m_mouseHook, code, wParam, lParam );   

    DWORD _vkCode = reinterpret_cast<KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*>( lParam )->vkCode;

    qDebug( "vkCode: %d, wparam: %d, lparam: %d", _vkCode, wParam, lParam );

    return CallNextHookEx( 0, code, wParam, lParam );
}
```

on pressing

```
vkCode: 162, wparam: 260, lparam: 3398032
vkCode: 165, wparam: 260, lparam: 3398032
```

on releasing

```
vkCode: 162, wparam: 257, lparam: 3398032
vkCode: 165, wparam: 257, lparam: 3398032
```

moreover, notice that when you press the key it sends it as **WM_SYSKEYDOWN (260)**, but when you release it the wParam is **WM_KEYUP (257)**. What the...? Why does it work in such way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the right alt-key (ALT-GR) is a shortcut for two keys - ALT and CTRL

You get WM_SYSKEYDOWN but WM_KEYUP because that's how the messages are defined - if you're expecting WM_SYSKEYUP, you get that when you release a key that is pressed in conjunction with the ALT key - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646287(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: that's so easy... xD, but what about the second part of the question? Why is this pressed as sys key and released as normal key?

Comment: another question, why then the ALT-GR + DEL doesn't display task manager?

Comment: Alt-gr Del doesn't do the same as ctrl-alt-del (any more) as it is handled at a lower level than normal key combinations. It did used to, IIRC